# Infinite scroll ordering by date

Tags: css, infinite-scroll

This is quite a difficult one for me to get my head around.

I've got a web page that is primarily designed for mobile phones and works fine on them.   The problem is on larger devices.

So I have a database of news stories which starts off by pulling the first 20 stories (ordered by newest first).

On a mobile that displays fine:

Story 1
Story 2
Story 3
Story 4

etc.   On a large screen the stories are displayed:

Story 1   Story 4   Story 7   Story 10

Story 2   Story 5   Story 8   Story 11

Story 3   Story 6  Story 9  Story 12

Which on the first page is fine, but as the page gets longer when infinite scroll kicks in the news stories all move down the left due to that column being the newest stories.  Effectively the user is seeing the stories that were on the first page.

Like I say, on mobile, it works fine because that's only showing one column.   Just wondering if anyone has any clever ideas?   The pinterest type design is css only:

```
*, *:before, *:after {box-sizing:  border-box !important;}


.row {
-moz-column-width: 18em;
-webkit-column-width: 18em;
-moz-column-gap: 1em;
-webkit-column-gap: 1em; 

}

.news-item {
display: inline-block;
margin:  0.2rem;
padding:  0.2rem;
width:  100%; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked on your issue. Please try this.

```css
*, *:before, *:after {box-sizing:  border-box;}
.parent{ width:100%; float:left; display:table; background:#232323; padding:10px;}
.parent .sub-row{ display:table-cell;}
.parent .sub-row .story{ width:100%; height:100px; margin:1px; background:#04CBEC; border:1px solid #000;}



@media only screen and (max-width:1024px) {
 
}


@media only screen and (max-width:767px) {
.parent{ width:100%; float:left; display:block;}
.parent .sub-row{ display:inline;}
.parent .sub-row .story{ width:24.5%; float:left;}
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
 <div class="sub-row">
     <div class="story">1</div>
        <div class="story">2</div>
        <div class="story">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-row">
     <div class="story">4</div>
        <div class="story">5</div>
        <div class="story">6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-row">
     <div class="story">7</div>
        <div class="story">8</div>
        <div class="story">9</div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-row">
     <div class="story">10</div>
        <div class="story">11</div>
        <div class="story">12</div>
    </div>
</div>
```